# Trouble creating a 3-dimensional table in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble creating a 3-dimensional table in **R** for 
[part 2a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc3S1.png).
The file can be downloaded here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1apU-ZVKJQJRzajFHmePDNjbsBgiByLU9/view?usp=sharing

I've been getting errors like the lengths are different sizes and that 'X' must have named dimnames. One and two dimensional tables don't give me any trouble. It's only when I want to do a three dimensional table when I struggle. Any help will be greatly appreciated. T

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: In my opinion, providing links to a google drive is problematic. First, I choose to not click on random links, a combination of paranoia and good security practice. Second, that link can (and will) at one point go stale, rendering this question unreproducible. Part of asking a good question is narrowing down the scope of the problem so that you can explain it with minimal code and minimal sample data.

Comment: Also, *please* show some of the code you tried, not just your raw data. This site works really well as a "let's help you fix your code and learn" place. When you don't show what you tried it's hard to correct your mistakes and it seems more like a "please write a solution for my problem".